# how to connect Hive in play framework?

Tags: java, database, hadoop, playframework, hive

I want to connect to [Apache Hive](https://hive.apache.org/) database from a PlayFramework application, but I can't find steps describing how to do it, whether is it possible or not. What are the steps to integrate Apache Hive with Play?

Comment: What have you tried? Which version of Hive? Which version of Play? Are you using Play Java or Scala?

Comment: i am trying to connect Hive 0.13.0.2.1.7.0-784 from play which is 2.4.x and i just opted play java. while running application i am getting exceptions related to hikaricp regarding connection pool.

Comment: You will need to disable HikariCPModule. Just add this to your `conf/application.conf` file: `play.modules.disabled += "play.api.db.HikariCPModule"`.

Comment: @marcospereira could answer this question? I have removed it and whats the next step sir?